# Android Studio proguard doesn't work

Tags: android, proguard, android-studio

I select "generate signed apk" in Android Studio and then check the "run proguard" checkbox in order for proguard to obfuscate my code. Unfortunately if the checkbox is checked the export of the .apk fails and just gives me this output:

> ProGuard: [TheNameOfMyProject] Der Befehl "java" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder >konnte nicht gefunden werden

Translated to english this would mean:

> ProGuard: [TheNameOfMyProject] The command "java" is misspeled or can't be found

Has anybody an idea what I could do to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!
Regards
Fleckdalm

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm having errors like this: can't find superclass or interface com.google.ads.AdListener

Comment: No, unfortunately I havent found a real solution! I just created a new android studio project and copied all my classes and resources to this project, then proguard worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I didn't use Android Studio to build a release apk yet, but try to look at this http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard

You probably need to configure gradle to use proguard, considering that android studio is using it to build

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't solve the problem! Proguard is already (automatically) configured right for android studio. There seems to be another problem...